# Warum werden manche Worte wie z.B. blümerant nicht oder kaum noch genutzt?

Tags: history

Warum werden manche Worte wie z.B. blümerant nicht oder kaum noch genutzt?

Mir ist klar, dass durch Sprachwandel neue Wörter hinzukommen, aber warum verschwinden manche Wörter?

Comment: fürchte, das ist ot, da es nicht direkt auf die deutsche Sprache bezogen ist.

Comment: Das gibt es in jeder Sprache und passt wohl eher nicht hier rein

Comment: ...daher bitte [Linguistics.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics) unterstützen!

Comment: Vielleicht ist es besser, die Frage stattdessen zu verschieben.

Answer (score 3):

Nun, aus dem gleichen Grund. Verschiedene Worte geraten einfach aus der Mode. Was früher das *knorke* wird zu *dufte* und später *cool*. (Vermutlich ist das heute auch nicht mehr in.) Neue Generationen prägen neue Wörter und distanzieren sich von den alten Bezeichnungen.

Manchmal ist es sogar noch extremer. Das Wort *Neger* war durchaus geläufig und stellte einfach nur den Fakt der dunklen Hautfarbe fest (es leitet sich von lat. *niger* ab: schwarz). Inzwischen wird es als rassistische Bezeichnung angesehen.

Comment: habe neulich mal den Ausdruck „voll holz“ gehört. Da wusste ich, dass ich alt bin.

Comment: In meiner Kindheit war "lässig" das Wort für "cool". "Echt lässig!"

Comment: Cool war früher hot. Zwischendurch gab es auch `fett` und `voll fett`, aber cool hält sich.

Comment: Und für sogenannt Weiße sagte man damals "Bleichgesicht", so rein faktisch?

Comment: @splattne Ich glaube mich zu erinnern, dass "Schmeckt lässig, die Schoki - richtig lässig" dementsprechend tatsächlich Werbespruchvorgänger von "It's cool, man" war :)